# Write multiple values into text file in Python?

Tags: python

I have created a set of 6 random integers and I wish to write 500 of them into a text file so it looks like this inside the text file:

x, x, xx, x, xx, x \n
x, x, x, xx, x, x    ....etc

(where x is an integer)

```
from random import shuffle, randint

def rn():
    return randint(1,49);

print "Random numbers are: " , rn(), rn(), rn(), rn(), rn(), rn()
```

There must be an easier way than pasting the last line 500 times?

EDIT: Why all the down votes? I'm sorry if this is a basic question for you guys but for someone learning python it's not.

Comment: Regarding the downvotes, I'd image people will recommend you complete a basic Python tutorial first: http://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-beginner-en-cxMGf?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096

Comment: Downvoted because solutions to your problem (e.g. Loops) are found in the most basic of programming tutorials; and this site is not meant to teach you the fundamentals of programming. It is expected that you do some work on your own (like reading a python tutorial) before asking a question.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. I will do that in future, regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
print "Random numbers are: "
for _ in xrange(500):
    print rn(), rn(), rn(), rn(), rn(), rn()
```

If you want to write to text file:

```
with open('Output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("Random numbers are: \n")
    for _ in xrange(500):
        f.write("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n" % (rn(), rn(), rn(), rn(), rn(), rn()))
```

Comment: That's great, but I want to print them into a text file, how would I do that? 

e.g

ext_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
text_file.write("Purchase Amount: " 'rn(), rn(), rn(), rn(), rn(), rn()')
text_file.close()

Comment: Could you tell me how to sort it by ascending number? I tried the sort() feature but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over a sufficiently-large generator.

```
for linenum in xrange(500):
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for-loop`:

```
from random import shuffle, randint

def rn():
    return randint(1,49);

with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    for _ in xrange(500):
        f.write(str(rn()) + '\n')
```

If you want 6 of them on each line:

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    for _ in xrange(500):
        strs = "Purchase Amount: {}\n".format(" ".join(str(rn()) 
                                                          for _ in xrange(6)))
        f.write(strs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely we have simple way :)

```
from random import randint

def rn():
    return randint(1, 49)

for i in xrange(500):
    print rn()
```

Answer (score 0):

Could use the following:

```
from random import randint
from itertools import islice

rand_ints = iter(lambda: str(randint(1, 49)), '')
print 'Random numbers are: ' + ' '.join(islice(rand_ints, 500))
```

And dump those to a file as such:

```
with open('output', 'w') as fout:
    for i in xrange(500): # do 500 rows
        print >> fout, 'Random numbers are: ' + ' '.join(islice(rand_ints, 6)) # of 6 each
```